# send one big packet of many small over TCP/UDP?

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, udp, package

I am sending coordinates of points to a visualizational client-side script via TCP over the internet. I wonder which option I should use:

1. concat the coordinates into a large string and send them together, or
2. send them one by one

I don't know which one the faster is. I have some other questions too:

1. Which one should I use?
2. Is there a maximum size of packet of TCP? (python: maximum size of `string` for `client.send(string)`)
3. As it is a visualization project should I use UDP instead of TCP?
4. Could you please tell me a bit about lost packet? When do they occur? How to deal with them?

Sorry for the many questions, but I really struggle with this issue...

Comment: The more you send at once with TCP the better, indeed same for UDP, if you can tolerate the delay while you gather more data to send. That question is really up to you.

Comment: @EJP: no, the OS (or the socket library) will concatenate TCP packets for you, so it doesn't really matter.  Overall, I think gen should ignore this issue and use the TCP connexion naively.  For example, using UDP is possible but seriously more complicated to get right.

Comment: @ArminRigo Thanks for your comment that's what I looked for. ('seriously more complicated' helps decision) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you send a string, that might be sent in multiple TCP packets. If you send multiple strings, they might all be sent in one TCP packet. You are not exposed to the packets, TCP sockets are just a constant stream of data. Do not expect that every call to `recv()` is paired with a single call to `send()`, because that isn't true. You might send `"abcd"` and `"efg"`, and might read in `"a"`, `"bcde"`, and `"fg"` from `recv()`.

It is probably best to send data as soon as you get it, so that the networking stack has as much information about what you're sending, as soon as possible. It will decide exactly what to do. You can send as big a string as you like, and if necessary, it will be broken up to send over the wire. All automatically.

Since in TCP you don't deal with packets, things like lost packets also aren't your concern. That's all handled automatically -- either the data gets through eventually, or the connection closes.

As for UDP - you probably don't want UDP. :)

Answer (score 0):

UDP has a maximum theoretical packet size of 65535, in reality this size is much lower and depends on operation systems and routing hardware. UDP does not have any mechanism to ensure data delivery, this make it much faster but unreliable without some hand crafted data protection mechanism.

TCP, you don't have to worry about packet size, if you try to send a bigger chunk then possible, wil be automatically and transparently split by the operating system for you. Sending small chunks of data can be inefficient due the overhead of the TCP communication, but even here, by default you have Nagle's algorithm enabled on most OS (See [Nagle's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm)). The algorithm basically tries to join small chunks of data, for most scenarios this is fast and efficient.